# How to search a raw disk for pattern and return its location?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, search, raw

How can one search a raw disk for a pattern and return its location?

The disk is not formatted, or at least, it uses a format unknown to Linux, `grep` and similar tools would not be useful.

A command line example would be appreciated. GUI based tool would also be fine, either Unix/Linux or Windows. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would `grep` not be useful?  Here is an example of `grep` returning the byte position of [the `EFI PART` signature](https://superuser.com/a/1399694/83694) at LBA 1 (starting at 512 bytes in) and at LBA -1 (at the end of the disk):

```
deltik@box52 [~]$ sudo grep -a -o -b 'EFI PART' /dev/nvme0n1
512:EFI PART
41661792:EFI PART
412075976:EFI PART
412207048:EFI PART
587940832:EFI PART
512110190080:EFI PART
```

Explanation of `grep` options:

- `-a`/`--text` – treat binary as text
- `-o`/`--only-matching` – returns only matching results
- **`-b`/`--byte-offset` – returns the byte offset of the match in the file**

Comment: Splendid, I completely forgot about grep `--text` option. Thank you.